# Objective-C Code Block Efficiency for a Bruteforcer

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

As far as CPU and memory usage, how efficient are C-style coding blocks in Objective-C? I'm creating a bruteforcing library for Objective-C and I need to optimize it as much as possible. The code block being used is called on every iteration of the bruteforcer.

Comment: "Efficient enough" is what I would say. There are probably many other optimizations you could make before worrying about the exact assembly the compiler produces, like using GCD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like with functional languages, the creation of the block (closure) may require an allocation on the heap (this certainly happen when you copy the block, maybe the compiler can avoid it when you just use the block in an inner frame).

Any case, if this happen outside of your loop, you pay the price once.  Calling a block should cost about the  same as calling a virtual method on a C++ instance object (since this is approximately the same task

Comment: Closure blocks (those that capture variables) are always allocated on the stack, not the heap. They are only moved to the heap when copied. Non-closure blocks are statically allocated.